# Spring Batch issue w/ CompositeItemWriter and ClassifierCompositeItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch in order to read data from the database (using partitioning) and writing the same to a set of files based upon entry keys - 1,2,3,4.

I have created a CompositeItemWriter which is a composition of two ClassifierCompositeItemWriter(s). Even though I have registered the individual writers as stream, I still get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
```

I even tried registering ItemWriter1 and ItemWriter2 as streams, but, that gives me a different error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream] for property 'streams[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
    ... 74 more
```

I have even implemented the ItemStream in the writers, but, it does not work yet.

```
public class WriterA1 implements ItemWriter<List<Object>>, ItemStream {
...
}
```

The following is the xml configuration:

...

```
<job id="abcJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    restartable="true"> 

    <step id="masterStep">
        <partition step="slaveStep" partitioner="abcPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="${grid-size}" task-executor="abcTaskExecutor" />
        </partition>            
    </step> 

</job>

<step id="slaveStep" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="abcReader" writer="abcWriter"
                processor="abcProcessor" commit-interval="${a}" skip-limit="${b}" retry-limit="${c}" >

                <streams>
                    <!-- 
                    <stream ref="ItemWriter1"/> 
                    <stream ref="ItemWriter2"/>
                     -->                        
                    <stream ref="WriterA1"/>
                    <stream ref="WriterB2"/>
                    <stream ref="WriterC3"/>
                    <stream ref="WriterD4"/>                                            
                    <stream ref="WriterA5"/>
                    <stream ref="WriterB6"/>
                    <stream ref="WriterC7"/>
                    <stream ref="WriterD8"/> 

                </streams>                

            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                ...                                     
            </listeners>                                                
        </tasklet>              
    </step> 


<bean id="abcWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>              
            <ref bean="ItemWriter1" />
            <ref bean="ItemWriter2" /> 
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>  

<bean id="ItemWriter1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="classifier">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
            <property name="routerDelegate">
                <bean class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Classifier1" scope="step"/>
            </property>
            <property name="matcherMap">
                <map>
                     <entry key="1" value-ref="WriterA1" />
                     <entry key="2" value-ref="WriterB2" />
                     <entry key="3" value-ref="WriterC3" />
                     <entry key="4" value-ref="WriterD4" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>     
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ItemWriter2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="classifier">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
            <property name="routerDelegate">
                <bean class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Classifier2" scope="step"/>
            </property>
            <property name="matcherMap">
                <map>
                     <entry key="1" value-ref="WriterA5" />
                     <entry key="2" value-ref="WriterB6" />
                     <entry key="3" value-ref="WriterC7" />
                     <entry key="4" value-ref="WriterD8" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>     
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="WriterA1" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterA1" scope="step">

 </bean>
 <bean id="WriterB2" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterB2" scope="step">

 </bean>
<bean id="WriterC3" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterC3" scope="step">

</bean>
<bean id="WriterD4" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterD4" scope="step">

</bean>
  <bean id="WriterA5" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterA5" scope="step">

  </bean>
  <bean id="WriterB6" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterB6" scope="step">

  </bean>
 <bean id="WriterC7" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterC7" scope="step">

 </bean>
 <bean id="WriterD8" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterD8" scope="step">

 </bean>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Which class (or even better, which bean) is throwing `org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException`?

Comment: WriterA1                                                                                                       (<bean id="WriterA1" class="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.WriterA1" scope="step">

 </bean>) is throwing an exception. My understanding is that any of the writers that are being invoked based upon the entry key is will throw the same exception.

Comment: Further to my note above: The item writers uses BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter in the overridden "write" method. Initially, I had configured the writers to use BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter through xml configuration, but, it was unable to detect the drive where the file had to be created stating that "Access is denied" which should not have occurred as I have admin priviledges on the local machine. Hence, I had to resort to writing the individual item writers.

Answer (score 1):

You have three types of writers. From top to bottom:

- `abcWriter` is a `CompositeItemWriter`. It implements `ItemStream` by delegating the `ItemStream` method calls to the delegates (here `ItemWriter1` and `ItemWriter2`), provided they implement `ItemStream`. Which is not the case. But even if they implemented `ItemStream`, you shouldn't separately register `ItemWriter1` and `ItemWriter2` as streams in the step configuration (there's another independent reason in the next bullet point).
- `ItemWriter1`/`ItemWriter2` are `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`s. This class doesn't implement `ItemStream`, so you **must not** register them as streams in the step configuration.
- `WriterA1` are of type `BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter` and therefore implement `ItemStream`. Because the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` that wraps them doesn't call their `ItemStream` methods (unlike `CompositeItemWriter`), you **must** register each one of them as streams in the step configuration.

But this is what you claim you have. Yet your scoped-scoped `WriterXX` beans are being proxied (with interface proxy mode) through singleton beans that don't implement `ItemStream` or `ItemStreamWriter`, instead only `ItemWriter`. Make sure that the classes you have inside the `<bean>` elements **do** implement `ItemStream`. You can also try creating the scoped proxy bean explicitly (using `ScopedProxyFactoryBean` and setting the `interfaces` property). Or you can try putting a breakpoint in `ScopedProxyFactoryBean::setBeanFactory` breaking when `targetBeanName` is contains the string `WriterXX` (it will be something like `stepScopedTarget.WriterD8`) and try to understand why the `ItemStream` interface is not being proxied.

Comment: I believe that's what I was doing below. It still does not work.                                                                                   
<streams>           
 <stream ref="WriterA1"/>
 <stream ref="WriterB2"/>
 <stream ref="WriterC3"/>
 <stream ref="WriterD4"/>                                            
 <stream ref="WriterA5"/>
 <stream ref="WriterB6"/>
 <stream ref="WriterC7"/>
 <stream ref="WriterD8"/>
</streams>

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @ridsoc I added some more hints.

Comment: The issue was in the implementation of the ItemStream interface while overriding the open (ExecutionContext executionContext) method wherein I had to set the BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter details and invoke the open method on the writer instance. I am now able to write the data to a single file which is set as a resource on the writer. However, my objective was to write the data to a file based upon the entry key. For example, if my entry key = 1, I want to create a file as File_1 and write the data to that file. I am unable to accomplish that. Please advise.

Comment: Further to my note above, the open method of the ItemStream is invoked before the processor phase is initiated and since, I need to create the file name based upon values retrieved from the database in my processor, my writer stream continues to be bound to the dummy file name and unable to switch to the pertinent file name while writing.